# How to Remove Class from element on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to toggle content information blocks on click of a button, which works when I click on another button, but when I click on the same button I want the information to hide, but it currently doesn't do anything.

The two sections are connected by a target attribute so that the correct content block shows up when the target button is clicked.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="cce-equipment-row">
    <div class="cce-equipment-column">
        <div class="cce-equipment-image-container">
            <img src="{{root}}static/images/machines/newco-20-1-digital-drip-brewer.png" alt="Newco 20:1 Digital Drip Brewer">
        </div>
        <p>NEWCO 20:1 DIGITAL DRIP<br/>BREWER</p>
        <span class="product-toggle-button" target="25">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cce-equipment-column">
        <div class="cce-equipment-image-container">
            <img src="{{root}}static/images/machines/nuova-simonelli-appia-espresso-machine.png" alt="Nuova Simonelli Appia Espresso Machine">
        </div>
        <p>NUOVA SIMONELLI APPIA<br/>ESPRESSO MACHINE</p>
        <span class="product-toggle-button" target="26">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cce-equipment-column">
        <div class="cce-equipment-image-container">
            <img src="{{root}}static/images/machines/nuovo-simonelli-mdx-grinder.png" alt="Nuova Simonelli MDX Grinder">
        </div>
        <p>NUOVA SIMONELLI MDX<br/>GRINDER</p>
        <span class="product-toggle-button" target="27">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cce-equipment-column">
        <div class="cce-equipment-image-container">
            <img src="{{root}}static/images/machines/starbucks-digital-interactive-bean-to-cup-brewer.png" alt="Newco Eco Series Drip Brewerq">
        </div>
        <p>STARBUCKS DIGITAL INTERACTIVE<br/>BEAN TO CUP BREWER</p>
        <span class="product-toggle-button" target="28">+</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="cce-equipment-info25" class="cce-equipment-info ams-multi-tasker-combo">
    <h1>NEWCO 20:1 DIGITAL DRIP BREWER</h1>
    <h2>Perfectly designed, right down to the latte macchiato</h2>
    <p>The IMPRESSA XJ9 Professional cuts an outstanding figure where the quality of the drinks served is just as important as aesthetics in architecture, ambience and design.</p>
    <p>It creates perfect latte macchiato, cappuccino, café crème, espresso and ristretto at the touch of a button.</p>
    <p>Meanwhile, the clear and symmetrical design, sophisticated chrome-plated bean container and brilliant silver finish add a touch of charisma.</p>
    <a href="#"><span>Download PDF Specs</span></a>
</div>
<div id="cce-equipment-info26" class="cce-equipment-info ams-wide-gem-snack">
    <h1>NUOVA SIMONELLI APPIA ESPRESSO MACHINE</h1>
    <h2>Perfectly designed, right down to the latte macchiato</h2>
    <p>The IMPRESSA XJ9 Professional cuts an outstanding figure where the quality of the drinks served is just as important as aesthetics in architecture, ambience and design.</p>
    <p>It creates perfect latte macchiato, cappuccino, café crème, espresso and ristretto at the touch of a button.</p>
    <p>Meanwhile, the clear and symmetrical design, sophisticated chrome-plated bean container and brilliant silver finish add a touch of charisma.</p>
    <a href="#"><span>Download PDF Specs</span></a>
</div>
<div id="cce-equipment-info27" class="cce-equipment-info crane-bev-max-media">
    <h1>NUOVA SIMONELLI MDX GRINDER</h1>
    <h2>Perfectly designed, right down to the latte macchiato</h2>
    <p>The IMPRESSA XJ9 Professional cuts an outstanding figure where the quality of the drinks served is just as important as aesthetics in architecture, ambience and design.</p>
    <p>It creates perfect latte macchiato, cappuccino, café crème, espresso and ristretto at the touch of a button.</p>
    <p>Meanwhile, the clear and symmetrical design, sophisticated chrome-plated bean container and brilliant silver finish add a touch of charisma.</p>
    <a href="#"><span>Download PDF Specs</span></a>
</div>
<div id="cce-equipment-info28" class="cce-equipment-info crane-merchant-media-snack">
    <h1>STARBUCKS DIGITAL INTERACTIVE BEAN TO CUP BREWER</h1>
    <h2>Perfectly designed, right down to the latte macchiato</h2>
    <p>The IMPRESSA XJ9 Professional cuts an outstanding figure where the quality of the drinks served is just as important as aesthetics in architecture, ambience and design.</p>
    <p>It creates perfect latte macchiato, cappuccino, café crème, espresso and ristretto at the touch of a button.</p>
    <p>Meanwhile, the clear and symmetrical design, sophisticated chrome-plated bean container and brilliant silver finish add a touch of charisma.</p>
    <a href="#"><span>Download PDF Specs</span></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.product-toggle-button').click(function(e) {
    $('.product-toggle-button--open').removeClass('product-toggle-button--open');
    $(this).toggleClass('product-toggle-button--open');
    $('.cce-equipment-info').hide();
    $('#cce-equipment-info'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your removeClass removes from the current button also if the `--open` class exists.

Then toggleClass would always only act as addClass

Try changing to:

```
 $('.product-toggle-button--open').not(this).removeClass('product-toggle-button--open');
                                  // ^^ exclude current button
```